# Web scraping all the newsletter info from the blog using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are 48 pages in this blog and i have scrapped the 1st page using web scraping. Using for loop i am trying to scrape remaining 47 pages and append the 47 pages dataframes to a 1st page dataframe but i am getting errors and in some cases i can only concat upto 2 pages dataframes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

No_of_pages_in_radletters = 48
page_urls = []
for i in range(2,No_of_pages_in_radletters):
        main_url = f'https://www.radletters.com/?page={i}&tag='
        page_urls.append(main_url)

for page in page_urls:
    response = requests.get(page)
    soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser')

    # Retriving newsletter names from each page
    newsletter_class = 'md:mt-2 mt-1 align-text-bottom inline-block font-semibold cursor-text'
    newsletter_title = soup.find_all('div',newsletter_class)
    newsletter_title_list = []
    for title in newsletter_title:
        newsletter_title_list.append(title.text.strip())

    # Retrieving newsletter description of each newsletter
    newsletter_desc_class = 'flex justify-center text-sm text-gray-600'
    newsletter_description = soup.find_all('div',{'class' : newsletter_desc_class})
    newsletter_description_list = []
    for desc in newsletter_description:
        newsletter_description_list.append(desc.text.strip())

    # Retrieving url of each newsletter
    newsletter_url_class = 'flex justify-center mx-8 mt-3'
    newsletter_url = soup.find_all('div',{'class' : newsletter_url_class})
    newsletter_url_list = []
    for url in newsletter_url:
        newsletter_url_list.append(url.a['href'])

    # Retrieving topic tags of each news letter    
    newsletter_topic_tags_class = 'md:mt-2 mt-1 flex flex-wrap justify-center'
    newsletter_topic_tags_class_2 = 'inline-flex text-sm hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-full px-3 my-1 mx-1 h-6 border border-gray-200 shadow cursor-pointer'
    newsletter_topic_tags = soup.find_all('div',{'class' : newsletter_topic_tags_class})
    newsletter_topic_tags_list = []
    for topic_tags in newsletter_topic_tags:
        newsletter_topic_tags_list.append(topic_tags.text.replace('\n','').rstrip().lstrip().replace('            ',','))

    dict_2 = {
    'Newsletter Title' : newsletter_title_list,
    'Description' : newsletter_description_list,
    'url' : newsletter_url_list,
    'Topic Tags' : newsletter_topic_tags_list
    }
    pages_df = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)

    # concatenating 1st page dataframe with the remaining pages dataframes
    page1_df = pd.concat(page1_df,pages_df)

print(page1_df)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The dataframes are not concatenating to the page1_df

Comment: Can you write the error message here?

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for pd.concat. What it expects as argument is not two data frames, but rather a list of dataframes. So I suggest you append your dataframes to a list in the loop, and then after/outside your loop you run pd.concat(list_of_dfs)

Comment: As there are many dataframes, how can i list the each dataframe.

Comment: df_list = [page1_df, page2_df, page3_df, ...], and then pd.concat(df_list). Or inside each loop do df_list.append(page_df) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> `page1_df = pd.concat(page1_df,pages_df)`

[`.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) expect a *list* of DataFrames to be passed as the main argument, so the correct usage would be

```py
    page1_df = pd.concat([page1_df,pages_df])
```

---

However, my preferred approach would be to collect all the DataFrames in a list and then to concatenate them at the end [outside the loop].

```py
pgdfList = [page1_df]
# for page in page_urls:
    ##### SCRAPE AND EXTRACT FOR dict_2 ##### 

    pgdfList.append(pd.DataFrame(dict_2))

page1_df = pd.concat(pgdfList)
print(page1_df)
```